# Generalizing a polynomial situation using combinations

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, proof-explanation

Generalize the polynomial relationship $$(1+x)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n{n\choose k}x^k$$ for all positive integers $n$ to the situation $$(1+x+y)^n.$$

This is similar to another problem I posted where I applied the relationship to $$(a+x)^n.$$ The method there was to factor our $a^n$, but here I don't see where I can apply that logic. My suspicion is to set a third variable $z$ equal to $x+y$ and see where that takes me, but I'm not sure.

Comment: This scenario is generally known as the multinomial expansion, you may read more about it here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem

Comment: So let me know if my logic is on the right track here.

e can think of this problem as having $n$ objects split between $1, x,$  and $y$. The degree of each term for a given $n=k_1+k_2+k_3$ will be $1^{k_1}x^{k_2}y^{k_3}$. Additionally, the coefficient of a given term will be $n\choose k_1,k_2,k_3$. So we can generalize this as $$(1+x+y)^n=\sum_{k=0}^{n}{n\choose k_1,k_2,k_3}1^{k_1}x^{k_2}y^{k_3}.$$

Comment: Rather than having a summation from $0$ to $n$, you should sum over all ordered triples $(k_1, k_2, k_3)$ such that $k_1 + k_2 + k_3 = n$.